# add first line to second line but separated with a tab

Tags: awk, grep

I am using  grep -B2 "average / return" /home/me/Desktop/file ,
how do I get the desired one-liner output where the first line
is added to the second line but separated from second line with a tab?

```
some words here
average / return 1,2 4 5,6 
--
other words here
average / return 4,3 7 9,4
--
```

desired output:

```
some words here     average / return 1,2 4 5,6
--
other words here    average / return 4,3 7 9,4
--
```

Comment: so the tab is between here and average

Comment: Note if you say `--no-group-separator` there won't be these `--` in between matches. This can come candy when processing that output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep it simple, lose the grep and pipe and other commands and just use awk on the original file:

```
awk '/average \/ return/{print prev "\t" $0} {prev=$0}' file
```

Feel free to add a line containing `--` between output lines if you feel that's useful:

```
awk '/average \/ return/{print prev "\t" $0 "\n--" } {prev=$0}' file
```

e.g.

```
$ cat file
it was the
some words here
average / return 1,2 4 5,6
best of times
it was the
other words here
average / return 4,3 7 9,4
worst
of times

$ awk '/average \/ return/{print prev "\t" $0} {prev=$0}' file
some words here average / return 1,2 4 5,6
other words here        average / return 4,3 7 9,4

$ awk '/average \/ return/{print prev "\t" $0 "\n--" } {prev=$0}' file
some words here average / return 1,2 4 5,6
--
other words here        average / return 4,3 7 9,4
--
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe the results to `sed`:

```
grep ... | sed '/^--$/!{N;s/\n/    /g}'
```

**Explanation:**

The sed command applies to those lines which doesn't contain the separator: `/^--$/!`. In the following block then `N` is used to get another line from input and append it to the pattern buffer. Finally the substitute command is used to replace the newline with 4 spaces: `s/\n/    /g`.

Lines containing the separator `--` will simply get printed. (Note that you can pass `--no-group-separator` to the grep command if you don't want them included in the output. Thanks @fedorqui)

**Output:**

```
some words here    average / return 1,2 4 5,6 
--
other words here    average / return 4,3 7 9,4
--
```

Comment: THANKS. I only did very small change    sed '/^--$/!{N;s/\n/\t/g}'  to get a tab between.

Answer (score 0):

You can try piping your output to the `tr` command, like this:

```
grep -B2 "average / return" /home/me/Desktop/file | tr '\n' '\t'
```